# What's the best way to store token signing certificate for an AWS web app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, identityserver4

I am using IdentityServer4 with .NET Core 2.0 on AWS's ElasticBeanstalk. I have a certificate for signing tokens. What's the best way to store this certificate and retrieve it from the application? Should I just stick it with the application files? Throw it in an environment variable somehow?

Edit: just to be clear, this is a **token** signing certificate, not an SSL certificate.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't really like the term 'token signing certificate' because it sounds so benign. What you have is a private key (as part of the certificate), and everyone knows you should secure your private keys!

I wouldn't store this in your application files. If someone gets your source code, they shouldn't also get the keys to your sensitive data (if someone has your signing cert, they can generate any token they like and pretend to be any of your users).

I would consider storing the certificate in [AWS parameter store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-paramstore.html). You could paste the certificate into a parameter, which can be encrypted at rest. You then lock down the parameter with an AWS policy so only admins and the application can get the cert - your naughty Devs dont need it! Your application would pull the parameter string when needed and turn it into your certificate object.

This is how I store secrets in my application. I can provide more examples/details if required.

**Edit** -- This was the final result from Stu's guidance

The project needs 2 AWS packages from Nuget to the project

- AWSSDK.Extensions.NETCORE.Setup
- AWSSDK.SimpleSystemsManagement

Create 2 parameters in the AWS SSM Parameter Store like:

- A plain string named `/MyApp/Staging/SigningCertificate` and the value is a Base64 encoded .pfx file
- An encrypted string `/MyApp/Staging/SigningCertificateSecret` and the value is the password to the above .pfx file

This is the relevant code:

```cs
// In Startup class
private X509Certificate2 GetSigningCertificate()
{
    // Configuration is the IConfiguration built by the WebHost in my Program.cs and injected into the Startup constructor
    var awsOptions = Configuration.GetAWSOptions();
    var ssmClient = awsOptions.CreateServiceClient<IAmazonSimpleSystemsManagement>();

    // This is blocking because this is called during synchronous startup operations of the WebHost-- Startup.ConfigureServices()
    var res = ssmClient.GetParametersByPathAsync(new Amazon.SimpleSystemsManagement.Model.GetParametersByPathRequest()
    {
        Path = "/MyApp/Staging",
        WithDecryption = true
    }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    // Decode the certificate
    var base64EncodedCert = res.Parameters.Find(p => p.Name == "/MyApp/Staging/SigningCertificate")?.Value;
    var certificatePassword = res.Parameters.Find(p => p.Name == "/MyApp/Staging/SigningCertificateSecret")?.Value;
    byte[] decodedPfxBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedCert);
    return new X509Certificate2(decodedPfxBytes, certificatePassword);
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection servies)
{
    // ...
    var identityServerBuilder = services.AddIdentityServer();
    var signingCertificate = GetSigningCertificate();
    identityServerBuilder.AddSigningCredential(signingCertificate);
    //...
}
```

Last, you may need to set an IAM role and/or policy to your EC2 instance(s) that gives access to these SSM parameters.

**Edit:** I have been moving my web application SSL termination from my load balancer to my elastic beanstalk instance this week. This requires storing my private key in S3. Details from AWS here: [Storing Private Keys Securely in Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-storingprivatekeys.html)

Comment: SSM Parameter Store is the way to go with this kind of thing.  The service roles can restrict access to the Parameter Store.

Comment: This sounds like what I am looking for. I'll try it out and Mark it as the answer when I am successful

Comment: The store seems to only have options for storing strings, but I have a binary PFX file that is password protected. I imagine there is a way to get it into a plain text format so I can make it an AWS parameter but I haven't figured out how yet. I can make a plain text ```.pem``` file but not sure how to get that into a .NET Core certificate object. If you have a process or some code for this, I would love to have an example.

Comment: I haven't stored binary data before in the parameter store. I think the next thing I would try is implementing much the same idea but with S3. Basically create a bucket, lock it down to admins and your application, then retrieve the cert at runtime. For extra security you can use AWS KMS to encrypt your certificate whilst its at rest. Have you used S3 before?

Comment: Just had another thought. Could you BASE64 encode the data and put that in parameter store? Then decode it on the way out? Might be easier if you have some code setup already.

Comment: @Stu Ha, I just came on to say I ended up BASE64 encoding it, but you beat me to it. I'd like to post a little code for other folks but you ultimately gave the right answer. Mind if I edit (add to) your answer and add some example code for others?

Comment: Great! Please go ahead.

Comment: @Stu and bzuillsmith
Thank you so much! I have been searching for exactly this for past 2 days. This is the way to go. Thanks again!